# Cannot access the quantity element inside the array in symfony controller script

Tags: php, symfony

In my symfony controller script, Im passing the quantity of my shopping cart. And im able to get the print_r as the following. The problem Im facing is I tried various ways to access the quantity for no success, can sombody help me on how  to access this quantity element

```
public function detailsAction($id, Request $request)
{
    $book = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Booklist')
        ->find($id);
    print_r($request->request->get('form'));
    die($request->request->get('form'));      

    return $this->render('books/details.html.twig', array('book' => $book, 'quantity' => 1));
}
```

OUTPUT with `print_r`

```
Array ( [quantity] => 1 [Add to Cart] => [_token] => Y8XHbH7lHphAFQ5lIjhQShoIleeSj9iGpen1rhxTBz4 ) Array
```

can somebody help me on accessing quantity??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have dumped `$request->request->get('form')` and there is a quantity in it. It should be easy to get the quantity.

```
$form = $request->request->get('form');
var_dump($form['quantity']);
```

Comment: Thanks alot my friend!!! one small favour,, in the detail.html.twig page i access other elements as follows
<li class="list-group-item">Category: {{book.category}}</li>
 <li class="list-group-item">Price: {{book.price}}</li>
like wise can you tell me how to access the quantity in details page

Comment: probably `book.price`. I need to clarify about `book` value